# Files created by Samba always sets g+rwx when ACL is used

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I'm using ACLs to enable rw access to both local and samba users, and noticed that group permissions is always set to rwx.

This is the ACL set on the test directory:

```
ubuntu@server:/test$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: samba
# group: samba
user::rwx
user:samba:rwx
user:ubuntu:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:samba:rwx
default:user:ubuntu:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Files created via Samba will result in `-rw-rwxr--+`:

```
ubuntu@server:/test$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:40 file1
```

To isolate the issue, I've set `create mask = 0000` on `smb.conf`:

```
/etc/samba/smb.conf:

[Share]
path = /test
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
map archive = no
create mask = 0000

ubuntu@server:/test$ sudo systemctl restart smbd.service

*Create file2 via Samba*

ubuntu@server:/test$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:40 file1
----rwx---+ 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:41 file2
```

We can find out that it's not ACL misbehaving by creating a file under the samba user:

```
ubuntu@server:/test$ sudo -u samba touch file3
ubuntu@server:/test$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:40 file1
----rwx---+ 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:41 file2
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:42 file3
```

So we can see here, it's samba that's setting g+rwx.

The problem goes away after disabling ACL:

```
ubuntu@server:/test$ sudo setfacl -b /test
ubuntu@server:/test$ sudo getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: samba
# group: samba
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x

*Create file4 via Samba*

ubuntu@server:/test$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rwxr--+ 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:40 file1
----rwx---+ 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:41 file2
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:42 file3
---------- 1 samba samba 0 Feb 19 03:43 file4
```

So is it correct to conclude that with ACL activated, samba will set g+rwx? Is it a bug, or did I miss something out?

I've scoured through the [samba docs](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) and tried all the options relevant to permissions: create mask, force create mode, inherit permissions, map archive,hidden,readonly,system, and am at a loss what else could be causing this.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, and it's really annoying me. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Doub nope, it isn't a crippling problem for me hence I just lived with it. Haven't got around to filing a bug report in the samba bugzilla.